# How to solve this problem by using recursive function

Tags: python-3.x

Write a recursive function that takes as input a list of integer numbers and returns the multiples of the numbers.

```
numbers_multiples = {}
lst_multiples = []
    
def multiples(*numbers):
    lst_numbers = list(numbers)
    lst_numbers.sort()
    n = lst_numbers[-1]
    for k in lst_numbers:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            if k % i == 0:
                lst_multiples.append(i)
                x = lst_multiples.copy()
                numbers_multiples[k] = x
        lst_multiples.clear()
    return numbers_multiples

msg = multiples(10,20,8,4,6)
print(msg)
```

That's my solution without using recursive.

Comment: It would be great if you could present a specific question here, we are happy to help answer questions but it is expected that you write your own solutions. It could be helpful to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach

```
def recurMultiples(*numbers):
    nmbrs = list(numbers)
    def find_mults(n, d):
        d[n] = [z for z in range(1, n+1) if n%z == 0]
        return d
    nmbrs = list(numbers)
    rslt = {}        
    while nmbrs:
        rslt = find_mults(nmbrs.pop(), rslt)
    return rslt
```

Comment: This is not recursion.

Comment: I think you will find the function find_mults is recursive

Comment: It isn't calling itself.

Comment: Okay, so you know that recursion requires the function to call itself.  This requires three essential things to occur within the function, (1) it must reduce the number of elements being processed each time it is called. (2)it must pass the results back to the caller, (3)It must detect no more work and pass back the last result.  So how would you accomplish these activities?